# Serial port in c++ , Unix

Tags: c++, unix, serial-port, arduino, termios

I wrote a code to connect, throught a serial port, mi computer to arduino.

This is arduino's code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;
const int pinServo = 2;
unsigned int angle;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    servo.attach(pinServo);

    servo.write(0);

}

void loop()
{
    if(Serial.available()>0)
    {  
       angle = Serial.read();

       if(angle <= 179)
       {
         servo.write(angle);
       }
    }
}
```

And this is c++'s:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <termios.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int angle;
    ofstream arduino;
    struct termios ttable;

    cout<<"\n\ntest1\n\n";

    arduino.open("/dev/tty.usbmodem3a21");

    cout<<"\n\ntest2\n\n";

    if(!arduino)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nERR: could not open port\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        if(tcgetattr(arduino,&ttable)<0)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nERR: could not get terminal options\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            ttable.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
            ttable.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
            ttable.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
            ttable.c_cflag |= CS8;
            ttable.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
            ttable.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;
            ttable.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);
            ttable.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
            ttable.c_cc[VMIN]  = 0;
            ttable.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

            cfsetospeed(&ttable,9600);

            if(tcsetattr(arduino,TCSANOW,&ttable)<0)
            {
                cout<<"\n\nERR: could not set new terminal options\n\n";
            }
            else
            {
                do
                {
                    cout<<"\n\ninsert a number between 0 and 179";
                    cin>>angle;
                    arduino<<angle;
                }while(angle<=179);

                arduino.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It should connect to arduino , then ask me a number between 0 an 179 and the send that number to arduino which aplly that number as an angle to a servo motor;
But it stops at `arduino.open("/dev/tty.usbmodem3a21")` .What can i do ?

Comment: What do you mean _"it stops"_? Do you get an exception, or does the program hang? Can you elaborate about the actual behavior please.

Comment: Sorry.it compliles , no errors no warnings, then it execute by terminal and i see the output "test1" and then the program stops , after "test1" there's no output, no text, nothing . And i also know for sure that is not a matter of time.

Comment: When you say _"it stops"_ do you get the shell prompt back? Also note you should use `std::endl` instead of `"\n"` for line endings. You might miss outputs, unless they're flushed (that's what `std::endl` does addtitionally vs outputting `"\n"`).

Comment: No , i think "it freeze"  make a better idea, the terminal remains opened , the program continues to run, but there is nothing as output

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to step through your code using the debugger, to narrow where exactly this happens. Also `tcgetattr()` used to get an `fd` parameter, not a `ostream` IIRC.

Comment: yes, the short answer is: this is when you debug. add prints/breakpoints

Comment: I'm more and more conviced that the `tcgetattr(arduino,&ttable)` causes the problem. Remember that `ofstream` has an automatic conversion to `bool` and thus to `int`. Supposed the `open` was good, you're passing `1` as `fd` parameter effectively, and change the attributes of stdin fd. Use the raw c-style `open()` to obtain an fd for your arduino device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problems appear in these lines of code

```
if(tcgetattr(arduino,&ttable)<0) {
    // ...
}
else {
    // ...

    if(tcsetattr(arduino,TCSANOW,&ttable)<0) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `arduino` variable is of type `ofstream`, where [`tcgetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tcgetattr.html) and [`tcsetattr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/tcsetattr.html) expect a file descriptor obtained with [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) at this point.

`ofstream` provides an automatic conversion to `bool` and thus `int` implicitely. Supposed the

```
arduino.open("/dev/tty.usbmodem3a21");
```

went OK, you are effectively passing `1` to `tcgetattr()` and `tcsetattr()`, which is the standard input file descriptor.

---

Solution is not to use a `ofstream` for `arduino`, but an ordinary file descriptor

```
int arduino = open("/dev/tty.usbmodem3a21",O_WRONLY);
```

Comment: Ok thank you , but another thing , are the flags settings allright for only output to arduinos ?

Comment: @DaddaBarba I don't know much about arduino. You'll need to know about the baud rate, parity etc. Also I'm not so sure, what `angle = Serial.read();` would expect from the serial port. Looks for me like transfering text data (as you tried with `arduino<<angle;`) isn't right.

Comment: Ok , thank you again . For serial.read() arduino should just take te values in te serial port file and put it in angle, but i also think there would be problems beacause angle is int , but i could also use a string to int converter so it is not so important arduino's code , it's made to have serial connections in easy ways